# How can I make the red spots transparented with the background image?

Tags: flutter

I have a widget which I can't make the red spots transparent with the background image. I was told to use Stack but when I use Stack the StretchMode are behaving really bad and make it look weird and stucky. I have purposely painted the red parts to make it more visible. Changin the color to either white or transparent won't effect anything.

My code:

```
class MainContent extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainContent({super.key});

  @override
  _MainContentState createState() => _MainContentState();
}

class _MainContentState extends State<MainContent> {
  double blurValue = 0.0; // Initial value for blur
  final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _scrollController.addListener(_onScroll);
  }

  void _onScroll() {
    double offset = _scrollController.offset;
    double blur = offset /
        100; // This will adjust blur value based on scroll, you can modify this for your preference
    setState(() {
      blurValue = blur;
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: CustomScrollView(
        controller: _scrollController, // Attach the scroll controller here
        physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        slivers: [
          SliverAppBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            expandedHeight: 270.0,
            elevation: 0,
            toolbarHeight: 20,
            flexibleSpace: Stack(
              children: [
                FlexibleSpaceBar(
                  background: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      image: DecorationImage(
                        image: AssetImage("assets/background_image.jpeg"),
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
                          Colors.black
                              .withOpacity((0.3 * blurValue).clamp(0.0, 1.0)),
                          BlendMode.overlay,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  stretchModes: [
                    StretchMode.zoomBackground,
                    StretchMode.blurBackground,
                  ],
                ),
                // Align(
                //   alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                //   child: Container(
                //     height: 40,
                //     decoration: BoxDecoration(
                //       color: Colors.white,
                //       borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                //         topLeft: Radius.circular(50),
                //         topRight: Radius.circular(50),
                //       ),
                //     ),
                //   ),
                // ),
              ],
            ),
            stretch: true,
          ),
          SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
              [
                //the container of the white board
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        topLeft: Radius.circular(50),
                        topRight: Radius.circular(50)),
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      _buildContainer1(),
                      ImageTextToggleContainer(
                        imagePath: "assets/barbershop1.png",
                        buttonText: "About Us",
                        height: 252,
                        text:
                            "Bye",
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 50),
                      ImageTextToggleContainer(
                        imagePath: "assets/barbershop2.png",
                        buttonText: "Contact",
                        height: 275,
                        text:
                            "Hey",
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 10),
                      _buildContainer4(),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

There's a code block I commented out, it's a temporary solution for the problem. Although it's like a bandage, I don't see it a useful solution for now.
I'm gonna add a small gif video of the app emulator to make it easy to understand where the problem come from. I'm a little bit new to Flutter, would much appreciate some assistance.

[The emulator:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhdd3.gif)

I tried implementing it using a Stack, it did work, but the entire StretchMode behavior changed and I'd like to keep the behavior I have right now.